# Меню выбора цвета

Tags: android

Как сделать небольшое выпадающее меню (не на все окно) из 6 ячеек в каждой свой цвет?
Думаю сделать через Spinner, но до конца еще не решил.

Comment: Делай через спиннер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае прекрасно подойдет Spinner

Информация о элементе:

https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/115-urok-56-spinner-vypadajuschij-spisok.html

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/spinner.php

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner

Как сделать разные цвета в ячейках:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23370412/android-spinner-different-background-for-each-row